# Flask App " def __html__(self) -> str:" syntax error

Tags: apache, flask, centos, python-3.6

I have installed Apache/2.4.6 in CentOS with Python/2.7.5, mod_wsgi/3.4. When I start the apache server, it is running, but the page gives "Internal error" message and in the error log  " def **html**(self) -> str:" syntax error, any idea how to solve this.

Flask wed app is not displayed.